# Replace line breaks except inside <pre> tags with brackets(<>) inside <pre> tags

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I replaced all the line breaks outside pre tags using the answer available in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188203/replace-line-breaks-except-for-ones-between-pre-tags).

```
\n(?![^<]*<\/pre>)
```

It was working fine until the content in pre tag had < or > brackets.

For example, with input of:

```
<p>Test contennt for regex
with line breaks</p>
<pre>code block 
with multi line content
working fine</pre>
<pre class="brush:C#">
test line break before 
open paranthesis < is not working fine
line breaks after paranthesis
is accepted
</pre>
```

Output is

```
<p>Test contennt for regexwith line breaks</p><pre>code block 
with multi line content
working fine</pre><pre class="brush:C#">test line break before open paranthesis < is not working fine
line breaks after paranthesis
is accepted
</pre>
```

which is not correct - not all line breaks are removed.

See [this regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cjZQO9/1/).

Comment: Don't parse HTML with a regular expression. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1255289

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\n(?=((?!<\/pre).)*?(<pre|$))/sg
```

The idea is to have a big lookahead. The

```
((?!<\/pre).)*?
```

repeatedly matches any character (including newlines with the `.`), and it is followed by

```
(<pre|$)
```

to require that the aforementioned character is *not* the `<` in `</pre`. Then, match either `<pre` (indicating that the original newline was *not* inside a `<pre`, or match the end of the file.

https://regex101.com/r/cjZQO9/2

With input of

```
<p>Test contennt for regex
with line breaks</p>
<pre>code block 
with multi line content
working fine</pre>
text
more text
<pre class="brush:C#">
test line break before 
open paranthesis < is not working fine
line breaks after paranthesis
is accepted
</pre>
text
```

output is

```
<p>Test contennt for regexwith line breaks</p><pre>code block 
with multi line content
working fine</pre>textmore text<pre class="brush:C#">
test line break before 
open paranthesis < is not working fine
line breaks after paranthesis
is accepted
</pre>text
```

Comment: Works has a charm. Thumbs up.